# R leaflet color scheme not working

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to color code markers on a map. Unfortunately, the markers are black (circled in red, because the black is faded!)

[image]

#### What I'm looking for

Color points based on `Percent_SEP12_Assets`, i.e.

- Less than 33% = red
- Between 33% and 66% = orange
- More than 66% = green

#### Code

```
sep <- read.csv("31R_SEP_assets_csv - Copy.csv")

Sub1 <- sep[grep("SEP.12", names(sep))]
sep$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep[4:7])

# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))

Color_Assets <- colorFactor(c("green","orange","red"),
                               levels = Percent_SEP12_Assets)

leaflet(data = sep[]) %>% 
  setView(lng = mean(sep$Longitude), lat = mean(sep$Latitude), zoom = 12) %>% addTiles()  %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude,  color = ~Percent_SEP12_Assets, popup = ~as.character(paste(Site, Percent_SEP12_Assets , sep=", ")))
```

#### dput(sep)

```
structure(list(Site = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Staten Island\\31R001", 
"Staten Island\\31R002", "Staten Island\\31R003", "Staten Island\\31R004", 
"Staten Island\\31R005"), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(40.508874, 
40.577256, 40.520825, 40.552373, 40.529697), Longitude = c(-74.244048, 
-74.100135, -74.211845, -74.195516, -74.187532), Windows.SEP.11 = c(63L, 
174L, 11L, 85L, 163L), Mac.SEP.11 = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L), Windows.SEP.12 = c(124L, 
185L, 9L, 75L, 23L), Mac.SEP.12 = c(0L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 0L), newCol = c(66.3101604278075, 
51.5235457063712, 73.2142857142857, 47.2049689440994, 12.3655913978495
)), .Names = c("Site", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Windows.SEP.11", 
"Mac.SEP.11", "Windows.SEP.12", "Mac.SEP.12", "newCol"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to reference `Percent_SEP12_Assets` within `~Color_Assets`

Corrected code snippit

```
leaflet(data = sep[]) %>% 
  setView(lng = mean(sep$Longitude), lat = mean(sep$Latitude), zoom = 12) %>% addTiles()  %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude,  color = ~Color_Assets(Percent_SEP12_Assets),  popup = ~as.character(paste(Site, Percent_SEP12_Assets , sep=", ")))
```

And output resembles this

[image]